# How to iterate through dictionary with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have ansible task to read dictionary variable from yaml i.e. subnets[0] (in all.yml of group_vars). What if I want to iterate through whole dictionary ?

```
- name: Create and/or update the subnet
      azure_rm_subnet:
        name: "{{ subnets[0].name }}"
        address_prefix_cidr: "{{ subnets[0].prefix }}"
        route_table: "{{ subnets[0].udr }}"
```

I tried with **with_dict: "{{ subnets }}"** and then i.e. *item.value.name*      or *item.name* but playbook fails with an error. Also what if not all objects have all properties, i.e. subnets[1].udr is missing, will it be possible to check for existence of property in the task ? My all.yml file is like below:

```
subnets:
  - 
    name: subnet1
    prefix: 10.2.1.0/24
    udr: rt1
    nsg: sg1

  -
    name: subnet2
    prefix: 10.2.1.0/24
    nsg: sg1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is closer to the [with_items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements) or [with_subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements) than it is with_dict

You would use it like this:

```
- name: Create and/or update the subnet
  azure_rm_subnet:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    address_prefix_cidr: "{{ item.prefix }}"
    route_table: "{{ item.udr }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ subnets }}"
```

The subelements is in the case you ever have subelements of such items. Check the docs for further usages of loop control features in ansbile.

Comment: it shows error: "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'name'